# Display of today's date in the form (asp.net core)

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to display today's date in my film creation form.

Controller:

```
    // GET: Movies/Create
    public IActionResult Create()
    {

        ViewData["IdGenre"] = new SelectList(_context.Genres, "IdGenre", "Name");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Movies/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name,DateDeSortie,Stock,IdGenre")] Movie movie)
    {


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            _context.Add(movie);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        ViewData["IdGenre"] = new SelectList(_context.Genres, "IdGenre", "Name", movie.IdGenre);
        return View(movie);
    }
```

Model:

```
 [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Date de sortie")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings =false,ErrorMessage ="La date est requise")]
    public DateTime? DateDeSortie { get; set; }
```

View:

```
 <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="DateDeSortie" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="DateDeSortie" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="DateDeSortie" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

Thank you for your help I have been stuck for several days

Comment: Please review your tags. This does not appear to be C code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code to your **View**. This will get today's date. This may or may not be what you're looking for.

```
@Html.Label("DateCreated", DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString().ToString(), new { @readonly = "readonly" })
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In my opinon, you could directly set the create view's input tag's value to today's value. To acheve this things, we could do it by using js or directly using `@DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="DateDeSortie" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="DateDeSortie" class="form-control" value="@DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")"  />
            <span asp-validation-for="DateDeSortie" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

Result:

[image]